# Javascritpt - Looping through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So i just started learning js and i can't solve this excercise:

> Create a file named `looping-through-arrays.js`.
>
> In that file, define a variable named pets that references this array:
>
> `['cat', 'dog', 'rat']`
>
> Create a for loop that changes each string in the array so that they
> are plural.
>
> You will use a statement like this inside the for loop:
>
> `pets[i] = pets[i] + 's'`

I tried something like this code but apparently it doesn't work:

```
let pets = ["cat", "dog", "rat"];
for(let i = 0; i <= pets.length; i++){
  pets[i] = pets[i] + "s";
};
console.log(pets);
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Your code looks right. The only issue I can see is that you use "<=" instead of "<" which will result in `i` being out of bounds in the end. Is that what you're experiencing?

Comment: Arrays are zero-based. The first element is at index `0`, the last on `<array>.length - 1`. `i <= pets.length` should therefor be `i < pets.length` (or `i <= (pets.length - 1)`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//Try this one   
 let pets = ["cat", "dog", "rat"];
    for(let i = 0; i < pets.length; i++){
      pets[i] = pets[i] + "s";
    };
    console.log(pets);
```

Comment: An answer without explanation is not an answer, it doesn't help anyone to learn.

Comment: Please explain why your answer is correct, *"Try this one"* doesn't help anyone